# take uiimageview image and convert to uiimage (swift4)

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage, swift4, uiimagepngrepresentation

I have a image view with a photo in it. I want to take that photo and convert it it to a UIImagePNGRepresentation. In a effort to store it as core Data. What I have coded right now does no work.

```
    import UIKit

class editVCViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var imageV: UIImageView!


    @IBAction func press(_ sender: Any) {


        var image = UIImage(named: self.imageV)
        var rep = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image!)

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have

```
var image = UIImage(named: self.imageV)
```

That won't compile, because `imageV` is an image view, not the (string) name of an image in your bundle.

Just say

```
var image = self.imageV.image
```